# Abbreviation for "read as", often used for spelling out euphemisms

Tags: abbreviations, euphemisms

A long time ago, I had a teacher who said you could write "lit." to mean "read this as". The typical example is to provide a tongue-in-cheek translation from English to English, such as:

> The power company charges an administrative (lit. bogus) fee on every bill.

The author of the sentence is telling the reader to read past the euphemism ("administrative") and understand the subtext that the power company really just wants to take their money for made-up reasons.

I just looked this up now, and couldn't find any reference material saying this was an accepted usage of "lit.". Maybe my memory isn't completely accurate?

Comment: I would use "i.e." in such circumstances, but that does not specifically mean "read as", or "literarily" and is an alternative suggestion rather than an answer to your question.

Comment: Here I think "lit." is being used to abbreviate "literally"

Comment: The shortest abbreviation would be an equal sign, although it might also make sense to put the original term that you are supplying a tranlation for in quotation marks: **The power company charges an "administrative" (= bogus) fee on every bill.**

Comment: ***lit*** is used as an abbreviation for ***literature, literary***. In any case, ***literally*** makes no sense in the cited context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/a7oa5o/what_does_it_mean_when_something_says_read/

> It's usually a guide to how the author wants you to read (i.e.
> interpret) a clause or phrase that may have obfuscated the true
> meaning. I'm struggling to think of good examples but maybe something
> like:
>
> "The politician resigned after his sex scandal, citing a desire to
> 'spend more time with his family' (read: sort out his marital
> problems)."
>
> Here, 'spend more time with his family' is a euphemism for fixing his
> marriage after cheating.
>
> Another example might be:
>
> "The scientist retracted her paper after discovering data
> irregularities (read: data manipulation)."

Answer (score 1):

The parenthetical should be

> (read "bogus")

This is often used as a sarcastic way to point out that the word being referenced is not being used honestly, and this is the actual way to understand it.

I don't think there's a common abbreviation. "lit." is usually used when you're providing a true synonym, not implying an alternate meaning.

Answer (score -1):

The word read, as a verb, can be used to suggest an interpretation:

> 7. 

> a. To attribute a certain interpretation or meaning to: read her words differently than I did.

> b. To consider (something written or printed) as having a particular meaning or significance: read the novel as a parable.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=read

“Lit”, presumably an abbreviation for literally, is an assertion of fact rather than judgment or interpretation.  Its use in the OP’s example isn’t correct.

Comment: *"The word read, as a verb",* Which word? *"“Lit”, presumably an abbreviation for literally,"* Is a presumption an answer or a comment?